# CloudFormation deploying ApiGateway methods inherit AWS_IAM from rootresource

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I've been building a bigger CloudFormation stack with resources like ApiGateway, Lambda, etc.

For the latest ApiGateway I've put AWS::ApiGateway::Methods directly on the / (rootresourceid) and when deploying from CloudFormation, the Authorizer on the AWS::ApiGateway::Stage would become AWS_IAM, though I've set a custom authorizer on the method and use DependsOn to let resources wait.

```
   Post:
    DependsOn:
      - AuthorizerApi
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: CUSTOM
      AuthorizerId: !Ref AuthorizerApi
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      ResourceId: !GetAtt Api.RootResourceId
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Join ['', ["arn:aws:apigateway:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/", !GetAtt PostLambda.Outputs.FunctionGetAtt, ":${stageVariables.environment}/invocations"]]
      MethodResponses:
      - ResponseModels:
          application/json: Empty
        StatusCode: 200
```

The funny part is, this is not a problem on resources under rootresource, so it seems to be an inheritance problem.

Anyone else who experienced this and what is the solution if the requirement is not to have a path under root?

Comment: if the requirement is not to have a path under root? -- Are you talking about creating API Gateway resource path which is not under root resource path ? or something else

Comment: I thought the observation was pretty clear, but when creating methods in ApiGateway using CloudFormation, I would suspect that it is entirely possible to have methods under the .RootResourceId and then have a custom authorizer on the rootresourceid, but when the Cloudformation stack is done, then the Authorizer is of type AWS_IAM, which is not what I would expect based on the code in my text.